# Is there a difference between 'decrescendo' and 'diminuendo'?

Tags: notation, dynamics

I'm a lifelong musician, and this is something I've always wondered about. I know that *decrescendo* translates to "decreasing" and *diminuendo* to "diminishing", but does this have any practical difference when it comes to playing or writing music? In my experience I've noticed *decrescendo* markings used over shorter bars and phrases, and *diminuendo* used more often to mark longer passages and pages where the `>` would be clumsy. Should I be interpreting these two marking differently when I am reading music?

Comment: the abbreviation  for both is dim. They mean the same. You can choose, it's up to you.

Comment: Not sure about this but it seems to me that decrescendo always (or mostly) follows a passage of increased loudness. I can't imagine a piece beginning with *mf* being marked *decrescendo* a few bars later. But I can imagine a piece starting the same way, but then marked *f*, and then a few bars later, *decrescendo*. In other words, I don't *think* you can decresc unless you've recently got louder. Perhaps it suggests a return to the level of the previous dynamic marking, but I've certainly never heard anything about them being interpreted differently from each other.

Comment: @Albrecht Hügli 1  I'm sure I've seen *decresc.* Or was it just the start of a *decresc  -  en  -  do*?

Comment: Yes, of course: dim. or decresc. I was wrong, sorry!

Comment: Dolmetsch defines them identically.

Comment: I see a lot of agreement here - if one of you puts it in an answer I would be happy to accept!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian You can certainly decrease the volume from a mf whether you call it decrescendo or diminuendo. Anyway, personally I always use either the term diminuendo or a hair pin symbol when writing music. And when talking the term "decrescendo" sounds too similar to the term "crescendo" while the term "diminuendo" is clearly different. It makes it easy to hear what you mean.

Comment: @Lars Peter Schultz I don't think you quite understood what I was trying to say. Can you think of an example of its use where there has so far only been a single dynamic marking in the piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some [discussion](https://books.google.de/books?id=deY7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=decrescendo+vs+diminuendo&source=bl&ots=pcFfyhfw16&sig=ACfU3U245NSAsEBakxe5hvhMjnip59DpRg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2mOby7_LpAhWS16QKHXvRBckQ6AEwFnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=decrescendo%20vs%20diminuendo&f=false) about whether Franz Schubert used the two terms to mean slightly different things, 'diminuendo' being a 'decrescendo' combined with a slight slowing down. Otherwise the two terms are used completely interchangeably.